# How to convert a PDF file to a DVD movie?

Tags: dvd, pdf

Each page would be navigable with the player's 'next' button. The result should have a directory called VIDEO_TS, to ensure it will play in old players.

Comment: Now, this is a novel question. I've wondered how to get the data *out* of a DVD's files where you have a slideshow as one of the extras on the disc, but I've never wondered how to *create* one, let alone from a PDF.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First that you need to do is convert PDF file into series of images - one image for one page. To achieve this we could use `convert` from ImageMagick program:

```
convert -scale 1600x1600 -density 300 pdffile.pdf somename.jpg
```

This command convert `pdffile.pdf` into series of `somename-NUMBER.jpg` files.

Next thing is to create slideshow from these files. For this we could use [dvd-slideshow](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/) tool.

```
dir2slideshow -n 'NAME' -t 5 DIR
dvd-slideshow -n 'NAME' -f NAME.txt
```

First command will create file with description of slideshow with name NAME, time for picture 5 sec from pictures in directory DIR. Second command will generate vob file that you need to burn to DVD (to VIDEO_TS dir). Quick introduction to dvd-slideshow you could read in [this blog](http://jcornuz.wordpress.com/2008/01/22/producing-a-dvd-slideshow/).

In example that I presented there pages are changed automatically (`-t` option in `dir2slideshow`). I'm not sure if navigation that you want could be easily achieved. My only idea is create DVD with chapters - one chapter for one JPG file and constantly loop each chapter until the 'next' button is pressed.

In this solution you could change slide time to 2 seconds and pause it after change, so when you unpause it next slide will be displayed after one second.

Comment: If the pdf has a lot of text, maybe try to use png and not jpg. I'm thinking about jpg artefacts...

Comment: How to do the `chapter` thing?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible, but maybe these two links will help you: http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/doc/x35.html and http://dvdauthor.sourceforge.net/doc/dvdauthor.html

Answer (score 1):

I would be very surprised if there is software that does this automatically, but if you take a screenshot of every page and save this as a graphics image, then most DVD creation software will allow you to take each image into a menu structure.

If its a long PDF, then its going to be quite a bit of work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [DVD-Slideshow](http://dvd-slideshow.sourceforge.net/wiki/Main_Page) is capable of doing this.